# error en la syntaxis de un if con la funcion "and" y los operadores de "mayor que" y "menor que" en PYTHON 3.8.1

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola soy nuevo en PYTHON (3.8.1) y tengo un problema (que nunca lo tuve antes) y es que al usar la sentencia if me da un error de SyntaxError

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion para adivinar el numero de otra persona
como un adivina el numero o como se llame

El import de random es porque voy a hacer un jugador contra la I.A

esto es lo que me dice :
(estoy en windows y programo con sublime text por si importa
todos los archivos son compilados con la consola de comandos de windows, no el idle
)

```
  File "adivina el numero.py", line 79
    if x > 20 and < 30:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

mi codigo EN PYTHON 3.8.1 :

```
import getpass
import random
import os

def cerrar_juego():
  print("quiere jugar otra vez?")
  o = input("(s/n) ")
  if o == "s":
   os.system("cls")
   x = int(getpass.getpass("pon el numero a elegir : "))

   if x < 20:
    lvl1()




def lvl1():


      print("el numero esta entre 0 y 20")
      adv = int(input("pon un numero : "))
      if adv == x:
        print("lo has logrado!!!")
        os.system("cls")
        cerrar_juego()

      if adv < x:
        print("pon mas la proxima")
        lvl1()

      if adv > x:
        print("pon menos la proxima")
        lvl1()



def lvl2():
  print("el numero esta entre 0 y 30")
  adv = int(input("pon un numero : "))
  if adv == x:
   print("lo has logrado!!!")
   os.system("cls")
   cerrar_juego()

  if adv < x:
   print("pon mas la proxima")
   lvl1()

  if adv > x:
   print("pon menos la proxima")
   lvl1()


def lvl3():
  print("el numero esta entre 0 y 20")
  adv = int(input("pon un numero : "))
  if adv == x:
   print("lo has logrado!!!")
   os.system("cls")
   cerrar_juego()

  if adv < x:
   print("pon mas la proxima")
   lvl1()

  if adv > x:
   print("pon menos la proxima")
   lvl1()




x = int(getpass.getpass("pon el numero a elegir : (nivel 1 = entre 0 y 20)    \n(nivel 1 = entre 0 y 30)    \n(nivel 3 = entre 0 y 50)"))

if x < 20:
  lvl1()

if x > 20 and < 30:
  lvl2()

if x > 20:
  lvl3()
```

Comment: el error te da porque estas comparando sin ninguna variable ahora puedes escribir en python `20 < a < 30`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sencillo, el error es que tienes que volver a comparar la *x* con 30, algo así:

```
if x > 20 and x < 30:
    lvl2()
```

Note desanimes. Cuando empezamos a programar, esos pequeños errores son un dolor de cabeza. Con el tiempo Lo iras superando, y encontrarás nuevos errores mucho más complicados, jeje.

Comment: Esos pequeños errores desgraciadamente son por largarse a programar sin antes haber leido la documentacion del lenguaje :(

Comment: @gbianchi no creo que alguien lea la documentacion completa, en mi caso voy practicando para aprender, sí leo la documentacion pero es tan extensa!

Comment: En mi caso leo toda la documentacion que puedo antes de largarme con algo, y asi evito un monton de errores en el camino ;) @IgmerRodriguez

Answer (score 1):

El error es que tienes que volver a especificar la variable que quieres comparar, es decir:

```py
if x > 20 and x < 30:
    codigo
```

Al no especificar, nuevamente el programa no sabe con que lo tiene que comparar.

[Operadores en python](https://entrenamiento-python-basico.readthedocs.io/es/latest/apendices/operadores.html)